# Make reverse geocoding without external APIs

Tags: javascript, html, reverse-geocoding

I have the following script on my HTML5:

```
<script>
    var myLocation = document.getElementById("my-location");

    window.onload = function() {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        else 
            myLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    };

    function showPosition(position) {   
        myLocation.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
</script>
```

This is working as expected. I am successfully retrieving the coordinates of the user, but what I would like is to retrieve is the country/city of the user. The examples that I saw used externals APIs that we need a key like the Google Maps API.

Can I do a reverse geocoding without those external APIs? Can't javascript do this natively?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the county code, you can try [codegrid-js](https://github.com/hlaw/codegrid-js). You can just include it in your site. It does not request any remote APIs, no dependencies on external geo-coding services.